# Build a DataFrame out of .txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a data frame out of a .txt file. The .txt file (which is a parameter I use in another program) looks like this:

```
a('s1','0')=1;
a('s2','0')=1;
a('s2','18')=1;
a('s3','0')=1;
a('s3','19')=1;
a('s3','21')=1;
a('s4','0')=1;
a('s4','20')=1;
```

Where s1, s2, s3... are routes, so route s1, route s2, route s3... for flights. And the following, '0', '18', '19' are id's of flights. So basically, route s1 is just flight '0', but route s3 goes first flight '0' followed by flight '19' and finally flight '21'.

What I want to extract from this txt file is a dataframe containing the route (s1, s2, s...) and the first and last flight operated in that route. So if route s10 has 5 flights, I only want the first and last flight of the route.

Is there a way in python or maybe pandas?

Comment: can you share how your txt file looks like

Comment: It is the one posted, "The file looks like this"

Comment: Since that is apparently a custom format, you'll have to write a custom parser for it first.

Comment: "***What I want to extract from this txt file is a dataframe containing the route (s1, s2, s...) and the first and last flight operated in that route.***" There's no last operator for `s1`, what do you expect in a situation like this?

Comment: In that situation, first and last flight are the same. So fro s1 flight '0' is first and last. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @M.Mike, did any of the answers worked? If yes, please mark the one that helped you. That way you will help others with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an easy task for regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

extract_route = re.compile(r"a\('(\w+)','(\d+)'\)=1;")

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    routes = f.readlines()

df = pd.DataFrame([extract_route.split(route)[1:3] for route in routes],
    columns=['Route', 'FlightID'])
```

Complementing the answer, you can now group the series by 'Route':

```
groups = df.groupby('Route')
```

With the groups in place, you can get the first and last flights using:

```
>>> groups.first()
      FlightID
Route         
s1           0
s2           0
s3           0
s4           0
>>> groups.last()
      FlightID
Route         
s1           0
s2          18
s3          21
s4          20
>>>
```

The main advantage of this approach is that you do not lose the intermediate flights information, in case you need them in the future.

Comment: Thank you accdias for the response, it get the following error: AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

Comment: My bad. I forgot ```findall()``` returns a tuple. I will fix my example.

Comment: It does not work when a route has more than 2 flights. Maybe is my fault since in the .txt sample I posted are just routes with two flights. Let me edit it (see s3)

Comment: That code is capable to handle any number of routes. What do you consider as not working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('data.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
df = pd.DataFrame([i[i.find("(")+1:i.find(")")].replace("'", '').split(',')
                   for i in data.split('\n')], columns=['route', 'flight_id'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  route flight_id
0    s1         0
1    s2         0
2    s2        18
3    s3         0
4    s3        19
5    s4         0
6    s4        20
```

Comment: Thank you Jeril for the quick response, It does not work when a route has more than 2 flights. Maybe is my fault since the .txt example I posted are just routes with two flights. Let me edit it.

Comment: can you share a sample having multiple flights

Comment: i am not able to find out the sample

Comment: a('s1','0')=1;
a('s2','0')=1;
a('s2','18')=1;
a('s3','0')=1;
a('s3','19')=1;
a('s3','21')=1;
a('s4','0')=1;
a('s4','20')=1;